# How do you remove dot character from string without calling sed or awk again?

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, regular-expression, string

I have a file called `hostlist.txt` that contains text like this:

```
host1.mydomain.com
host2.mydomain.com
anotherhost
www.mydomain.com
login.mydomain.com
somehost
host3.mydomain.com
```

I have the following small script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

while read host; do
        dig +search @ns1.mydomain.com $host ALL \
        | sed -n '/;; ANSWER SECTION:/{n;p;}';
done <hostlist.txt \
        | gawk '{print $1","$NF}' >fqdn-ip.csv
```

Which outputs to `fqdn-ip.csv`:

```
host1.mydomain.com.,10.0.0.1
host2.mydomain.com.,10.0.0.2
anotherhost.internal.mydomain.com.,10.0.0.11
www.mydomain.com.,10.0.0.10
login.mydomain.com.,10.0.0.12
somehost.internal.mydomain.com.,10.0.0.13
host3.mydomain.com.,10.0.0.3
```

My question is how do I remove the `.` just before the comma *without* invoking `sed` or `gawk` again?  Is there a step I can perform in the existing `sed` or `gawk` calls that will strip the dot?

`hostlist.txt` will contain 1000s of hosts so I want my script to be fast and efficient.

Comment: Any reason why `dig +short` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe because some of the hosts in my hostlist.txt are just hostnames, not FQDNs so I'm using +search to resolve them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `sed` command, the `awk` command, and the removal of the trailing period  can all be combined into a single awk command:

```
while read -r host; do dig +search "$host" ALL; done <hostlist.txt | awk 'f{sub(/.$/,"",$1); print $1", "$NF; f=0} /ANSWER SECTION/{f=1}'
```

Or, as spread out over multiple lines:

```
while read -r host
do
    dig +search "$host" ALL
done <hostlist.txt | awk 'f{sub(/.$/,"",$1); print $1", "$NF; f=0} /ANSWER SECTION/{f=1}'
```

Because the `awk` command follows the `done` statement, only one `awk` process is invoked.  Although efficiency may not matter here, this is more efficient than creating a new sed or awk process with each loop.

#### Example

With this test file:

```
$ cat hostlist.txt 
www.google.com
fd-fp3.wg1.b.yahoo.com
```

The command produces:

```
$ while read -r host; do dig +search "$host" ALL; done <hostlist.txt | awk 'f{sub(/.$/,"",$1); print $1", "$NF; f=0} /ANSWER SECTION/{f=1}'
www.google.com, 216.58.193.196
fd-fp3.wg1.b.yahoo.com, 206.190.36.45
```

#### How it works

awk implicitly reads its input one record (line) at a time.  This awk script uses a single variable, `f`, which signals whether the previous line was an answer section header or not.

- `f{sub(/.$/,"",$1); print $1", "$NF; f=0}`

  If the previous line was an answer section header, then `f` will be true and the commands in curly braces are executed.  The first removes the trailing period from the first field.  The second prints the first field, followed by `,`, followed by the last field.  The third statement resets `f` to zero (false).

  In other words, `f` here functions as a logical condition.  The commands in curly braces are executed if `f` is nonzero (which, in awk, means 'true').
- `/ANSWER SECTION/{f=1}`

  If the current line contains the string `ANSWER SECTION`, then the variable `f` is set to `1` (true).

  Here, `/ANSWER SECTION/` serves as a logical condition.  It evaluates to true if the current matches the regular expression `ANSWER SECTION`.  If it does, then the command in curly braces in executed.

Comment: Thank you @John1024!  I didn't know that awk didn't need to be within the loop (I thought that it would only act on the last line if it was outside).  Is `f` an arbitrary variable or is `f{}` an explicit part of awk's functionality?

Comment: Your welcome.  `f` is an arbitrary variable.  You can actually put before the `{}` complex  logical conditions.  `f` is just a very simple logical condition: it is true if nonzero, false if zero.

Comment: @Linoob Note that in the second command, `/ANSWER SECTION/` plays the role of logical condition, analogous to the role `f` played in the first command.  I have updated the answer to discuss this.

Answer (score 8):

`dig` can read in a file containing a list of hostnames and process them one by one.  You can also tell `dig` to suppress all output except the answer section.

This should give you the output you want:

```bash
dig -f hostlist.txt +noall +answer +search | 
    awk '{sub(/\.$/,"",$1); print $1","$5}'
```

`awk`'s `sub()` function is used to strip the literal period `.` from the end of the first field.  Then `awk` prints fields 1 and 5 separated by a comma.

NOTE: entries in `hostlist.txt` that do not resolve are completely discarded - they do not appear on stdout OR stderr.

(Tested on Linux and FreeBSD)

Answer (score 6):

Change your invocation of `gawk` to the following:

```
| gawk '{print substr($1,1,length($1)-1)","$NF}' >fqdn-ip.csv
```